# Node Debugging in WSL

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 WSL in VSCode.

I have the extensions remote development, WSL, I have node installed, nvm as well.

When in work in a remote WSL and try to debug I don't have the Node option at all.

When I run the file I get:

`No debugger available, can not send 'variables'`

My launch.json is as follows:

````
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}```

Can someone please help me fix it by adding Node.js option so I can properly debug?

Thanks a lot in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you found the solution eventually?

I add similar issue, I could get things working only by specifying the node binary path explicitly.

1. get your node binary path by issuing:
   `which node`
2. then add it to your `launch.json` config:

   ```
   {
       "name": "Launch Program",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.js",
       "request": "launch",
       "skipFiles": [
           "<node_internals>/**"
       ],
       "type": "pwa-node",
       "runtimeExecutable": "/home/user01/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/bin/node"
   },
   ```

Still there is something is wrong going on, even though I simply the setup tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

Answer (score 0):

After many many hours of struggling with this, I finally got mine working. It's clunky and awkward, but it does at least work, and enables me to debug.

In `tsconfig.json` set `"sourceMap": true`

Use this launch config

```json
{
  "name": "Attach",
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "node"
  "port": 9229,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**"
  ]
}
```

In `package.json` add this script (replacing the filename with yours)

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect ./dist/src/index.js"
  }
}
```

With all of that setup, to debug the application, execute this in the terminal window

```bash
npm run debug
```

Then press F5 to attach to the process.

Note that you need to enable source maps in `tsconfig.json` and the launch config.